# How do I get a server's ID with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm not using discord.ext, just discord. I need to find the server ID that the bot is currently connected to. I've done some googling, but could only find 1 stack overflow question and the answer wasn't helpful.
I could really use this, thanks!

Comment: From where? A command? From event? Show some code..

Answer (score 8):

You didn't specify how you want to get the server ID, 
so here is an example using the command, you get ID of server, where this command was used.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def getguild(ctx):
    id = ctx.message.guild.id
```

You can check it and output with print for example `print(id)` will give  output like this: [image] Also you can just add `ctx.send(id)` and Discord Bot will send this ID to server chat.
Discord guild id have integer type. Now you got ID and can manipulate with it. 
Read more about it [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#guild)

Comment: OP specified not using `discord.ext`, your answer’s solely based on the premise that they’re using the `commands` Extension. However, the original question really needs some expansion  (with code).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to get the guild (server) ID without using `discord.ext`, assuming you're using:

```py
async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message) -> None:
    ...
```

to capture messages/commands in your bot.

`message.guild.name`
and
`message.guild.id`

Would hold the relevant information.

```
Guild Name: 'My Server Name'
Guild ID: '299299999999999991'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have to use the `ctx.message.guild.id` or `ctx.guild.id`

Here is some example code

```
@client.command(pass_context = true)
async def getserverid(ctx):
   serverId = ctx.message.guild.id
   await ctx.send(serverId)
```

Comment: I don’t know how to do this without discord.ext

Answer (score 0):

Without discord.ext it would be:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        print(f"Guild id: {message.guild.id}")
```

Comment: you should use a multiline codeblock instead of the in line codeblock.